# Can't run tests with Robolectric 4.0.1, 'packageDebugUnitTestForUnitTest' fails

Tags: android, kotlin, robolectric

My robolectric tests aren't working after upgrading to Robolectric 4.0.1.

In my gradle configuration I am using `testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true` and in gradle.properties `android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=true`.

Here's a dummy test to use as en example:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
internal class MyRobolectricTests
{
    @Test
    fun my_test()
    {
        val someItems = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext().resources.getStringArray(R.array.array_of_strings)

        assertEquals(10, someItems.size)
    }
}
```

I am experiencing 2 separate problems:

1. If I run the test then I am getting the following message:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':packageDebugUnitTestForUnitTest'.
>
>   > Illegal character in opaque part at index 11: jar:file:C:\myproject\build\intermediates\apk_for_local_test\debugUnitTest\packageDebugUnitTestForUnitTest\apk-for-local-test.ap_

2. If I remove the `testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true` option from the gradle config file then I am getting the following error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>   #0x7f030007

In the line `val someItems = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()...`

Why did the tests work with version 3.6.1 but now they don't?

Comment: Robolectric 4.0.2 has some issues on Windows, which we're working on: http://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3955 -- you could try using Android Gradle Plugin 3.3 beta: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/

Answer (score -1):

Remove `android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=true` from gradle.properties. It helps in my case.

Please refer all the comments on this issue [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3955)